# error inflating class nativeactionmodeawarelayout

Tags: android, android-widget, android-support-library, android-tabs, android-api-levels

I've already ready all posts related about my question, but didn't find a solution which worked for my case.

I'm trying to get sliding tabs via this tutorial : http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/04/Android-Material-Design-Sliding-TabLayout.html

It looks pretty modern even if it doesn't use design tabs from API 21, and it's an important point because I want my application to be available for most android versions.

Unfortunately, I'm facing an error:
( I know I used depreciate Method, is it really important ? If it is, how can I get through? )

```
12-21 02:56:14.676: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.slamingdev.daniillerusseapp/com.slamingdev.daniillerusseapp.MainActivity}: 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
```

I think it's because I'm using a too recent version of the support v7, which doesn't contain `android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout` anymore.

I didn't post my code, as it's exactly same code as in the tutorial link above.

Please Check out this updated tutorials on sliding tab layout at http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-material-design-tablayout-icon.html

Comment: please try check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564918/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-internal-widget-nativeactionmodeawarela

Comment: As I said it in my post, I already checked theses answers but it didn't tackle my case.